# How to Insert a mail in MYSQL from Linux Terminal

Tags: mysql, linux, terminal

Well I got stuck with this. While I was trying to make an Insert into at mysql terminal (using linux btw) I got caught with the @ (at) expresion which it can´t be inserted, is this something about regular expresions or does it uses a custom input for this character?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the command you ran and the error you received?

Answer (score 2):

`@` in a string means nothing to sql servers, but a bare `@` will be seen as a variable reference, so most likely your query string is syntactically incorrect:

```
good: INSERT INTO yourtable (email) VALUES ('someone@example.com');
bad:  INSERT INTO yourtable (email) VALUES (someone@example.com);
```

Comment: ok thanks I made the insert correctly as you said. any other similar condition tu use simple quotes (')?

Comment: If the text you're inserting contains `'`, then you'll have to escape them: `insert ... VALUES ('O\'Brien')`. Since you're doing this from the mysql monitor, there's nothing that'll do this for you automatically. You'll have to escape things yourself.

Comment: Ohh ok, so it works for any text string no matter if it contains regular expressions or not, right? but what about numbers, because it does work with numbers without simple quotes

Comment: numbers are always numbers, because tables and field names are not allowed to start with a digit, so there's no way to misinterpret `somefield=42` as wanting to set somefield equal to the value of a field named `42`. It'll ALWAYS be seen as `put the value 42 into the field somefield. Strings, on the other hand, CAN be misinterpreted as sql reserved words, field/table names, etc.., which is why they need quoting (and escaping if necessary).